# E4 - Entirely POM Driven

Tags: maven, manifest, pom.xml, e4

I am currently working on a project which is an E4 Application driven by both POM and manifest files at different levels. Due to some dependency issues, our team is considering moving to completely POM driven, with auto generated manifest files on Maven build. Research into this issue has surfaced little to no information, leaving us unsure if such a system is even possible.

Is this even a feasible setup? Are there any plugins which can help with this endeavor?

Thanks

Comment: Have you gathered some information on that subject? I would be interested. I don't find much either.

Comment: @XavierBouclet After further research our team decided it wasn't feasible due to our project constraints. While it may be possible in general, it would work best on a brand new project. Sorry I can't point you to any substantial sources of information beyond that; as you stated, little is out there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply